# How do I exit this function?

Tags: matlab

Essentially its built like so:

```
.If

..other stuff

.Else

..For

...For

....If (this is where I need to be able to break out of the whole thing)
```

I've tried using `return`, and `break`, but they just are not working for whatever reason. I added in a ticker and it appears that the `break` command isn't working?

The code just continues going on and repeating the for loop even AFTER it is 'broken' in the `If` statement.

My function is only about 150 lines long, so I've been able to study it closely, and this seems to be where the problem is.

Comment: Why didn't `return` work?

Comment: To supplement gnovice's comment - why not put the two loops in a separate function and just `return` when done...?

Comment: I know why break didn't work, and I suspect return failed for the same reason, it just continued the for loop after exiting the <c>if</c> statement. I think I'm going to try the <c>try</c> thing as well since its an assignment so I can only use 1 (homemade) function, which is the assignment itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you have

```
for (...)
    for (...)
        if (true) 
            break;
    end
end
```

you'll only break out of the *inner* loop. But, of course, the *outer* loop will continue as normal!

Breaking out of nested-loops is one of the **very few** reasonable use cases for a `goto`. However, MATLAB does not have a `goto`, so you'll have to repeat yourself in some way or another:

```
for (...)

    for (...)
        if (condition) 
            break;
    end

    if (condition) 
        break;

end
```

An equally ugly yet common and less verbose way:

```
try 

    for (...)

        for (...)
            if (condition) 
                error(' ');
        end       
    end


catch %#ok

    (code you want to be executed after the nested loop)

end
```

or, to be pedantic,

```
breakout_ID = 'fcn:breakout_condition';

try 

    for (...)

        for (...)
            if (condition) 
                error(breakout_ID, ' ');
        end       
    end


catch ME

    % graceful breakout
    if strcmp(ME.Identifier, breakout_ID)
        (code you want to be executed after the nested loop)

    % something else went wrong; throw that error
    else
        rethrow(ME);
    end

end
```

Or you build a (nested) function containing just that nested loop, and use `return` to break out. But that may not always give the most "obvious" code structure, as well as cause you to have to write lots of boilerplate code (subfunction) and/or have unforeseen side effects (nested functions), so...

Personally, I favor the `try/catch` above.

Comment: Thanks! That last one seems like exactly what I needed! The majority of the rest of my code was also within those 2 for loops, which wasn't ideal, this is perfect!